# Not getting expected output in an armstrong numbers program

Tags: java, numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class arm
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the lower number");
    long l=scan.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Enter the upper number");
    long u=scan.nextLong();

    System.out.println("The armstrong numbers in this range are");
    long t=l;
    while(t<u)
    {
        long hold=t;
        long ram=0;
        long f=0;
        long multiplier=0;
        while(hold>0)
        {
            ram=hold%10;
            hold=hold-ram;
            hold=hold/10;
            ram=multiplier;
            ram=ram*multiplier;
            ram=ram*multiplier;


            f=f+ram;
        }
        if(f==t)
        System.out.print(t+" ");
        t++;
    }
}
}
```

Eg: If my input is 1 and 999 then output is 
`1 153 370 371 407`

This is the program I wrote to print the numbers that are armstrong numbers in a given range, why is it not working?

FYI, An armstrong number is a number that is the same as the sum of the cubes of its digits, so 371=(3^3)+(7^3)+(1^3)=27+343+1=371

Tell me if you want any more details.

Comment: What is not working? there seems to be no compiler errors. Are you sure your logic is correct?

Comment: I think so, and the program is compiling correctly, but it seems to stop working after taking the values for the upper and lower numbers.

Is there a way to check my logic?

Comment: Is your range included in both ways? So, to say, if lowest num is 2, and highest is 5, then the range would be 2,3,4,5 or 3,4 ?

Comment: No, my range is one way, so if l=1, and u=5, then the range is 2,3,4, but I have tried entering the numbers both ways.

Comment: It's more easier, and better to apply the formula to get Armstrong number. I would do in such a way: create an ArrayList of numbers (corresponding to the range), iterate it and applying the formula to each number, to check if it's Armstrong, if the condition is true (number is Armstrong), then print the number.

Comment: Look like it just takes very long time to execute, when you try to input in large number. Notice that in each second, one computer can do 10^9 operations, while for `long`, it can go up to 10^18 digits

Comment: @samhain be specific. Saying "it's not working" is much too vague. Tell us what the inputs are, what the expected output is and what the actual output is.

Comment: @JBNizet The input is 1 for l, and 999 for u.
The expected out put would include 1 
153 
370 
371 
407

Comment: @PhamTrung, no The program does terminate, it does't wait

Comment: @drgPP, how do I do this? I'm just learning Java, don't now arrays yet

Answer (score 1):

Your line `ram = multiplier` is causing the error.
You can do this instead of that line and the `ram = ram * multiplier line`

```
f = f + ram *ram *ram;
```

Explanation : `f` contains sum. `ram` contains the last digit. And you have to get the sum of cube of all digit. You extract all digits , find their cube (`ram * ram *ram`) and add it to `f`

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked. Why was this causing the error?

Comment: I get your explanation, but why was the ram=multiplier not working?

Comment: You had `multiplier = 0` and set `ram = multiplier` thus everytime you were setting 0 to ram .`ram` should hold last digit

Comment: Also you were multipling `ram * multiplier` that was like `0 * 0`

Comment: OHH. So if I wanted to got that way, I should have done multiplier=ram, that way it would have worked, yes?

Comment: Did it work ? A/T me, it should have . -Just wanted to know-

Answer (score 0):

As i posted in the comment, here is my version of checking Narcissistic (Armstrong) number, based on [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) described in Wikipedia:

Below is the full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StackOverflow {


    public static void main (String[] args){
        getNarcisist();
    }

    public static void getNarcisist(){
        System.out.println("Insert lowest number");
        Scanner lower = new Scanner(System.in);
        Long lowestNum  = lower.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Insert highest number");
        Scanner highest = new Scanner(System.in);
        Long highestNum = highest.nextLong();
        highest.close();
        lower.close();
        ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for(long i=lowestNum+1;i<highestNum;i++){
            list.add(i);
        }

        for(Long checkedNumber : list) {
            int length = String.valueOf(checkedNumber).length();
            long[] digitsRepresentation = new long[length];
            int i=0;
            Long temp = checkedNumber;
            while(temp>0) {
                long digit = (temp%10);
                temp = temp/10;
                digitsRepresentation[i]=digit;
                i++;
            }

            System.out.println("Now is checkin number: "+checkedNumber);
            if(checkedNumber == calculateNarcisist(digitsRepresentation)) {
            System.out.println("Found narcisist number: "+checkedNumber);
            } 
        }


    }

    public static long calculateNarcisist(long[] input){
        long sum=0;

        for (int i=0; i<input.length;i++){
            double pow = input.length;
            double narcisistSum = Math.pow((double)input[i], pow);
            sum +=narcisistSum;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

This program, calculates the range (non-included) between two inputed numbers, gets the digits of each number in range and calculate the Armstrong sum, if it finds any number which Armstrong sum is equal to checked number, than it prints it to screen.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but OP is asking for armstrong number not narcisit . Armstrongs are raised to powee 3 not the number of digits